# print the changed variable before the calculation is done

Tags: c, variables

in a c program, i want the variable 'count' to be printed at the beginning of the program. But the calculation for the value of 'count' is done later. How do you accomplish this?

```
    count = 0;
    printf("the value of count is : %d", count);
    count = 20;
```

I know in this case, the output is 0. But I need 20 to be printed.

Comment: You cannot print something before it is calculated.

Comment: so, there is no way to print a calculated value in the beginning?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve really?

Comment: I need to find the no. of cases, print the 'no. of cases' in the beginning, and then display the cases later.

Comment: No, it's against the laws of nature.

Comment: You can print a calculated value in the beginning, but you cannot print an unknown value, because it is not logic. There is no any programming language capable of divinate the future. You have to be more specific.

Comment: Calculate the number of cases then print, then print the cases...

Comment: yeah, but while printing the cases, i could calculate the number, so it's like double work.

Comment: It isn't double work given that you have the requirement to print the number of cases before printing the details.  You either have to decide not to print the number of cases first, or you have to compute the correct value and then print the supporting data.  You can't have your cake and eat it.

Answer (score 4):

The idea of program flow is that commands are executed in a certain order. You don't expect the waiter to bring you your meal before you have told him what you want to eat - but that seems to be what you are asking.

Of course the order of lines in a file is not necessarily the order of execution: you have have a line "at the start of the file" that is executed later: for example

```
#include <stdio.h>

// we define the print statement here:
void printCount(count) {
  printf("the count is now %d\n", count);
}

int main(void) {
  int count = 20;
  printCount(count); // but we don't execute it until we get here...
  return 0;
}
```

Now your "print" statement occurs (in the file) before you assign (calculate) `count` - but of course they are being executed in the correct order.

**afterthought**

If it's a case of printing "the number of cases is n", you could of course do

```
printf("the number of cases is ");
cases = 5; // whatever math is needed happens here...
printf("%d\n", cases);
```

and the result is

```
the number of cases is 5
```

just as you wanted... this works because there was no carriage return after printing "the number of cases is" - so the number follows when you have figured it out.

**edit**

Reading through the question and comments one more time I think I understand what your issue is. You have a loop that counts a number of inputs (say the number of lines in a file) and want to print both the total number of cases (not known before the loop) and something about each case (discovered during the loop) but without having to loop over all the data twice. There *is* a way to do this, using a print buffer. If data access is really slow and looping twice would be prohibitive, this might be an option. You would want to initialize a "sufficiently large" print buffer in memory and use `snprintf`to create the string you need. In reality you *will* "loop over" the bytes in the output string twice but there is minimal performance penalty (compared to everything else). Incomplete example:

```
int count=0,num, sofar=0;
char buf[2000];
// assume file is opened and handle is fp
while(true){
  if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &num) <1) break;
  sofar+=snprintf(buf+sofar, "%d\n", 2*num); // some "math" on number for each "case"...
  count++;
}
printf("There were %d lines\n", count);
printf("Here they are multiplied by two:\n");     
printf("%s\n", buf);
```

Obviously the above is incomplete - you need to check for errors, open/close the file, etc - I am just trying to point out the principle - this way you only loop through the data (file) once but print the count before the contents.

Answer (score 0):

you can't print 20. how can you print a variable before its get initialized?